# media query for print in CSS prints scaled down version in Chrome 54+

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am using `@media print` to design some labels. After the Chrome 54+ upgrade the print seems to be in a scaled down version. The relative sizes and distances between the elements remain the same; however the printing appears zoomed out or scaled down when it prints. Works fine on Chrome 53. Any idea why this would occur?

Comment: I don't got the same problem you're having. Can you show some code so that I can test it?

You can also check caniuse.com too see if you can use that properties. There is also nothing that says there should be a problem  with chrome.

http://caniuse.com/#search=print

Comment: Could you find a workaround this?

Comment: Out of curiosity are you testing in a Terminal Services environment?  I'm seeing issues with Chrome 54 Printing in Terminal Services.

Comment: Same problem here. Confirmed that it worked fine in Chrome 53, and also that using the latest Chromium (future Chrome 56) build, it will continue working the messed up way it's working right now.

Comment: I just added max-width : 100% and works fine now. it is a bootstrap issue and the Chrome versions interpretation  of it .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran in to this bug because our application uses the Bootstrap 3 framework. I discovered (by accident actually) that if you have a DIV with a bootstrap container class to wrap your content (common for Bootstrap pages), this bug will be triggered. A simple workaround is to force the container to be 100% width when printing by adding the following CSS style after your bootstrap CSS.

```css
@media print {
   .container {
      width: 100% !important;
      min-width: auto !important;
   }

}
```

This has resolved the print size problem introduced in Chrome 54 in our application.

I have also reported this bug to the Chrome team who have acknowledge it...
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660058

Comment: I actually figured the same. This  is exactly the issue. Works now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not anywhere near a complete fix, but it got us running for our app. These are corporate users on Chrome, printing documents and labels.

Targeted to Chrome only using browser hack.

```css
// Chrome 54+ specific browser hack for printing
// http://browserhacks.com/#hack-ac2480b5c83038f2d838e2a62e28a307
@media print and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution: .001dpcm) { body { zoom: 150%; } }
```

Comment: I don't know why this bug reappeared in 2023. But your code (shortened down) helped: @media print { body { zoom: 150%; } }

Comment: This hack will also apply to Safari, so you'll fix Chrome, but break Safari.